# React setAttribute in interval function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React and I have a simple js slider, which one I try to rewrite on React. My problem is setting attribute on specific element from array in startSlider(). How I can set attribute in setInterval() ? Error is :  createdImages[(this.state.slide % 3)].setAttribute is not a function

And here is the code:

```
var createdImages = [];

class Slider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      imagesArray: ["css", "html", "javascript"],
      slide: 0
    };
  }

  creatingImages() {
    return (createdImages = this.state.imagesArray.map((image, index) => {
      return (
        <img
          key={image}
          className={index === 0 ? "active" : ""}
          src={require(`./img/${image}.png`)}
        />
      );
    }));
  }

  startSlider() {
    createdImages[this.state.slide % 3].setAttribute("class", " ");
      createdImages[(this.state.slide + 1) % 3].setAttribute("class", "active");
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      slide: prevState.slide + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.sliderInterval = setInterval(() => this.startSlider(), 2500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing a wonky assignment to a global variable? Why aren't you attaching `createdImages` to state, or even just an instance property?

Comment: @Li357 good point, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to set an attribute manually on the image elements, you could use the active slide in the state instead to choose what slide to give the class `active`.

**Example**

```
class Slider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imagesArray: ["css", "html", "javascript"],
      slide: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.sliderInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return {
          slide: (previousState.slide + 1) % previousState.imagesArray.length
        };
      });
    }, 2500);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.sliderInterval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.imagesArray.map((image, index) => {
          return (
            <img
              key={image}
              className={index === this.state.slide ? "active" : ""}
              src={require(`./img/${image}.png`)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: working perfect now, I dont know why yet, but it's working haha. Thank you

Comment: @Bart32 Awesome! You're welcome. In short, it updates the `slide` variable in an interval, and starts from 0 again if it reaches 3. It then checks the array index for this `slide` variable in the render method (which is rerun every time `setState` is called), and if they are the same, the image is given the `active` class.